# splitting a dictionary into original format python

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a data file with names and numbers in such as:

```
james 343
john 343
peter 758
mary 343
```

I then use this code to turn it into a dictionary

```
userAccounts = {}
with open("E:\file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       userAccounts[key] = val

print userAccounts

newUserName = raw_input ("welcome, please enter your name, a number will be assigned to you")
userAccounts [newUserName] = 9999

print userAccounts
```

After adding the new person to the dictionary I would then like to write the new data over the old file however it writes over it as a dictionary, like :

```
{'james': '343', 'john': '343', 'peter': 758, 'fred': '9999'}
```

Then when I run the program again it cannot create the dictionary as the file is not in a bad format.

I would like to split the data into its original format to save to the file so I can keep running the program and adding names.

Sorry if this is easy I am new to coding and searching for the answer online has killed me.

Comment: You should use a raw string(`r"E:\x0cile.txt"`), otherwise Python will interpret `"E:\file.txt"` as  `"E:\x0cile.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the file and write each key-value pair to it:

```
with open(r"E:\file.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key, value in userAccounts.items():
       f.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, value))
```

This uses the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to put your key and value pair together on one line with a space in between and a newline character at the end, just like in your original file.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("E:\file.txt", 'w') as f:
  for user in userAccounts:
    f.write('%s %s\n' % (user, userAccounts[user]))
```